# Javascript to disable button residing inside a user control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using a "user control" which contains a button and other controls. I am using it in an aspx page. I want to diable the button using Javascript. By any chance, is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you mean by 'disable', but to take it away you get the element in Javascript in an object and use:

```
element.style.display = "none";
```

That completely takes it away, to just make it invisible use:

```
element.style.visiblity = "hidden";
```

To get the element in an object, the easy way is once you know the value of the id attribute, say it's id="bla", you use

```
element = document.getElementById("bla");
```

You can also just use:

```
document.getElementById("bla").style.display = "none"; // etc
```

Of course, CSS is far simpler, use:

```
#bla {display:none;} /* etc, can also be with visiblity */
```

But I'm not really sure what you mean with 'disable', also, disabling with JavaScript is NOT a form of good security, JavaScript can be turned off, also, the source can be inspected to just work around it.

Edit: Some clarification: display:none; just treats it as if it isn't there at all. visiblity:hidden; makes it completely transparent, but other elements around it are still placed as if it were there.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to set the attribute "disabled" it is possible

```
$(element).attr("disabled", "disabled"); // jQuery
element.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled"); // js
```

If you really need to remove literally you can use [jQuery Remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$(element).remove();
```

or do it by hand

```
var el = document.getElementById(id);
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```

if just hide is enough, I recommend doing this with CSS

Comment: -1: Removing an element is not necessary. Disabling it means that it can be re-enabled in the future and used again.

Comment: You can save the removed element and add it later.
Edit: added `disabled` property

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove or hide the element as the other answers suggest. Form elements in HTML have a `disabled` attribute for a reason. With Javascript you would select the button element (however you are selecting elements) and set the `disabled` property like this:

```
buttonElement.disabled = true;
```

To reenable the button:

```
buttonElement.disabled = false;
```

Obligatory jQuery:

```
$(buttonSelector).attr('disabled', true); // Disable
$(buttonSelector).attr('disabled', false); // Enable
```